# solution of an IVP of an ode with laplace

Tags: laplace-transform

$\epsilon u_{x x}(x,t)-u(x,t)+w_{x}(x,t)=0$
And the initial condition is $u_{x}(0,t)=0$

How can I find the solution of this ode by using Laplace transform

Comment: The Laplace transform is linear, so take the Laplace transform of each term in the equation (and initial conditions) to get a new equation that will be algebraic, not a differential equation (in u). Recall the rule for taking the Laplace transform of derivatives (Wikipedia will help) when doing this. Once you've solved the algebraic equation, you can then invert the Laplace transform to give the result.